# intervals and frequencies in matlab without using hist

Tags: matlab

.I have a dataset of 50 and it is poisson and another one is normal .and from these datasets i generated random data sets according to their distribution type for each other. now by assuming the original one is the observed and the created is the expectd . how can i calculate the intervals and the frequencies for these datasets with out hist ,because hist gives different intervals for the observed and the expected and that will make the data set rejected in chi2gof. heeeeeeellllllppp

Comment: `hist` isn't recommended anymore. Read the documentation for `histogram`. It has parameters for controlling how the data is binned.

Answer (score 0):

The `hist` function is no longer recommended by Mathworks. Instead you should be using the [`histogram`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) function. It supports specifying the edges of the bins of the histogram.

Here is a simple test run showing how to generate a 50-bin histogram of two data sets with different ranges, while ensuring that the bins are the same:

```
x = rand(10000, 1) * 3;
y = rand(10000, 1) * 2 + 2;
low = min([x; y]);
high = max([x; y]);
histogram(x, linspace(low, high, 50));
histogram(y, linspace(low, high, 50));
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you ,but i need the values of these intervals to be equals for both the original (observed)and the generated(expected) so i can apply it in chi square test with matlab

Comment: @MahmoodIbrahemAhmed, I'm not sure what you're asking for then - my x and y would be replaced with your observed and expected. The histograms generated have identical intervals, in this case divided into 49 equally sized intervals from the lowest value seen to the highest value seen. The return values of the histogram function should give you the frequencies in the bins for you to use in your analysis.